# How to add Subnets of a Vpc to VpcConnector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet, pulumi

How do I add subnets of a vpc to vpc connector? I tried adding like this:

```
const vpcConnector = new awsc.apprunner.VpcConnector("vpc-connector", {
  securityGroups: [ec2SecurityGroup.id],
  subnets: pulumi.output(vpc.getSubnetsIds), // ERROR HERE!
  vpcConnectorName: "my-vpc-connector",
});
```

But it shows error as:

```bash
1. Type 'Output<(type: VpcSubnetType) => Promise<Output<string>[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Input<Input<string>[]>'.
```